# How to set SQL row into scalar variable?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. They have one column which indicates if it is stock or bad stock. Now I want to set value when status 'Y' that means total bad stock value & when status 'N' total stock value from sale & sale return table.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    sr.IsBadStock as Status,
    CASE 
       WHEN sr.IsBadStock = 'Y' 
          THEN (SUM(srd.Qty)) 
       WHEN sr.IsBadStock = 'N' 
          THEN SUM(srd.Qty)
    END
FROM
    SaleReturn sr, SaleReturnDetail srd
WHERE 
    sr.SaleInvNo = srd.SaleInvNo 
    AND sr.Department = srd.Department 
    AND sr.Company = srd.Company
GROUP BY 
   sr.IsBadStock
```

Here is my output:

```
Status | (no column name)
-------+------------------
N      |   60
Y      |   390
```

I want these two values set scalar variable which name is `@stockQty` for first row & `@badStockQty` for second row so that I can do some calculations later. Is it possible?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also please tag the **actual RDBMS** you're using - SQL is just the query language.....

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Using MS SQL Server

```
DECLARE @Good int
       ,@bad int

SELECT @bad =
          SUM(
              CASE
                  WHEN r.IsBadStock = 'Y' THEN [Qty]
                  ELSE 0
              END),
      @Good =
          SUM(
              CASE
                  WHEN r.IsBadStock = 'N' THEN [Qty]
                  ELSE 0
              END)
FROM Returned r

PRINT @good
PRINT @bad
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @mikeinman thanks for your consideration.I am using MSSQL and It return always 'Y' value.'N' value remain always 0.But i want *bad* & *good* value at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a basic `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    sr.IsBadStock as Status,
    SUM(srd.Qty)
FROM
    SaleReturn sr
JOIN SaleReturnDetail
  ON  sr.SaleInvNo = srd.SaleInvNo 
  AND sr.Department = srd.Department 
  AND sr.Company = srd.Company
GROUP BY 
   sr.IsBadStock
```

Note the switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax.